# Convert HTML data into Text format - Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Web Driver to extract data points from LinkedIn profiles. In this example I want to extract each skill from the skills section but the data is extracted as HTML format.

When trying to convert the HTML code to text I get the attached error message.

[image]

```
from parsel import Selector  
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/davidcraven/Downloads/chromedriver')

# get profile URL
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/AnyProfileURL')

# assigning the source code for the web page to variable sel
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)

# get skills
skills = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "skills searchable has-several ")]').extract()

newtext = BeautifulSoup(skills, "lxml").text
```

Comment: `skills` is a list.  You probably want the _content_ of the list, i.e. `skills[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon but I just need the output to be converted into plain text. If you paste the HTML code into this site https://www.textfixer.com/html/html-to-text.php it makes the format like this '
• Event Planning• Advertising• CRM• Leadership• Account Management• So I would like to do the same in my code so it can be outputted in the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the text from a page using selenium.

Try this: 
The following code would print the texts in the console.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile")

elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
print(elem.text)

driver.quit()
```

---

**Edit:**

In your code the `sel.xpath().extract` returns a list to the `skills`. 
You have to iterate the list to get the texts. The following code prints the found texts in the console.

```py
from parsel import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")

# get profile URL
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/AnyProfile')

# assigning the source code for the web page to variable sel
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)

# get skills
skills = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "skills searchable has-several ")]').extract()

# newtext = BeautifulSoup(skills, "lxml").text
for skl in skills:
    print(BeautifulSoup(skl,"lxml").text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to export each separate data point to excel so it needs to be formatted rather than the HTML format.

Comment: You can do that directly with selenium too. Find the needed nodes using locators and then get the text of that node.

Comment: I am aware of this but with LinkedIn its much harder as there is no unique identifier or incrementing value added to each attribute. The class names and id's are used more than once through the page.

Comment: I've updated the code. The extract method returns a list. You have to iterate it.

Comment: Thank you that is great, I hope you dont mind me asking but if I am writing the variables to a csv how can I include that for statement into this below. Would i have to assign the list contents to a separate variable? writer.writerow([name.encode('utf-8'),heading.encode('utf-8'),
location.encode('utf-8'),skills,])